# Is there any significance to the use of the number "28" in Stargate?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

The Stargate was found in 19**28**, and in Cheyenne mountain, the Stargate is on the **28**th floor.

Is this a coincidence, or intentional? Is there any significance to this use of the number 28?

Comment: I am guessing… nothing?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to assume that the two numbers are connected in any way? Are there, for example, [other prominent uses of the number elsewhere in the show](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/47) that might make you think that it's a thing

Comment: You are newish here. I recommend visiting the [Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help), particularly the part on [closed questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), and the part about [on-topic questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: One swallow does not make a summer, and two isn't much more conclusive. Compare this to the repeated use of "five-six" in Cordwainer Smith's stories, where many characters are given names that translate to "five-six" in different languages, e.g., Tiga-belas, Veesy Koosy, Fisi, Limaono, etc., and the author even slips his hand in one place by stating that Earth names were based on numbers, and in another by remarking that a character was in the wrong place because "most of the people sent here have names ending in 5 or 6." Two uses of a number in a long series don't amount to much.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron that would make a better answer than a comment in my (not wearing my mod hat) opinion

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Thanks. Since my reply was largely negative I decided just to comment. Your positive response makes a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

### There's no special significance

The number 28 is special neither in Egyptian nor in Norse mythology, the two main sources for inspiration in the Stargate franchise.

The [Egyptians considered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Egyptian_mythology)

> 2, 3, 4, 7, and their multiples and sums.

As sacred or special.

But the article only mentions 28 as the maximum number of cubits the Nile could flood, so that particular multiple (28) doesn't seem special.

Likewise in [Norse mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Norse_mythology):

> appears to put special emphasis on the number nine. Along with the number 27

But besides 28 being one off of 27, there's no mention.

---

Also, I couldn't find any other references to 28 in the [Stargate Fandom Wiki](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate_Wiki), and the two instances you found seem unrelated (i.e. it's not a set of dates, or a set of floor numbers.)

Comment: You're assuming it has no other inspiration. Gould planet is PX-888. Greek gematria of `Jesus` is 888.

Comment: @Bob but why would that planet be related to the Greek Gematria for Jesus? You can find single connections between fiction and real world, but that coincidence doesn't mean there's a correlation without a reason behind it.

Comment: The Gould claim to be gods. Jesus is the Son of God ie God. Gematria for Jesus is 888 -> Gould planet is PX-888.